# 404 error when typing 'www.johndoe.com/something'

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm building my portfolio as a front-end dev and it's still under developmentt. To test it out I used FTP to upload the files to my justhost domain which is a success. Now, say my site is www.johndoe.com (okay fine, my actual site is 'hassanefall.com' to make this easier to understand :)).

(I'm using angularjs for the routes) I want to go to a specific route/page: www.hassanefall.com/about. The about page works when i navigate through clicking the links.

But, when I type in the url the exact url path, there's a 404 error page.

I have '/work', '/contact', etc. and whenever I type in the url 'www.hassanefall.com/contact' directly without navigating to it, a 404 page occurs. It's as if the file for each page/route doesn't exist.Help?

Here's the code.

**Note:** I removed the hash from the url using base '/' and $relocationProvider. If there's an answer to this it's greatly appreciated.

```
var app = angular.module('mySite', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
    })
    .when('/projects', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'views/projects.html'
    })
    .when('/service', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'views/service.html'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html'
    })
    .when('/contact', {
        controller: 'ContactController',
        templateUrl: 'views/contact.html'
    })
    .when('/portfolio/:id', {
        controller: 'ItemController',
        templateUrl: 'views/item.html'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

*If you need more code sample please let me know. :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server should support HTML5 mode. What is happening here is that the server is looking for your client side route ('contact', for example), and does not find it. That's why you have 404 not found error.

Another solution is to go back to hash mode..

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at it and if it's the server then I'll return to hash mode. Is there an alternative such as the pushstate? I'm new to all this. :)

Comment: You can use pushState but you will loose the ability for deep linking etc. I would avoid that. P.S: if my answered help please mark it as answer / add credit (: